# Offline production build in Angular 9

Tags: angular, build

In angular 6, When I executed *ng build --prod* I got a bunch of files in my dist project folder and index.html that had

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My project</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.5510f6725adb16e901a5.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.a19b2f1d90e9baecaab8.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.07ef95a019972121cea2.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

So I opened index.html and my app worked offline just fine.
But I now updated to angular 9 and after *ng build --prod* I got this index.html

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My project</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.387b68bbf04bb28b1761.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.0811dcefd377500b5b1a.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.0811dcefd377500b5b1a.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.61df131d802a89ddffe2.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.77d2d1471503030c423e.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es2015.e2388ceeb931e40e846b.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.e2388ceeb931e40e846b.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

script tags have now this type="module" and when I'm trying to open index.html the browser throws an error

```
Access to script at 'file:[path_to_my_app]/runtime-es2015.0811dcefd377500b5b1a.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
runtime-es2015.0811dcefd377500b5b1a.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
index.html:1 Access to script at 'file:[path_to_my_app]/polyfills-es2015.77d2d1471503030c423e.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
polyfills-es2015.77d2d1471503030c423e.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
index.html:1 Access to script at 'file:[path_to_my_app]/main-es2015.e2388ceeb931e40e846b.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

When I change type="module" to type="text/javascript" my app kinda works(it works in chrome but firefox throws `` Error: "Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)" ``)

How to make angular 9 project to properly build for offline usage? Also, another related to this question: What should I do so that after I run *ng build --prod* angular doesn't dump every file in the main folder of the project but only index.html and puts the rest of the files into some other folder in this directory(for example "data"), so that the main folder would look user-friendly.

Comment: I've always used a very simple node.js server script to test these builds locally. Requires, of course, Node.js but I thought if there is now no way to test it by simply opening the `index.html` file in the browser this would be probably the easiest.

Comment: > 'if there is now no way to test it by simply opening the index.html'
What? Really? But I NEED to make it work locally. It serves as a desktop app, not a web one. Am I forced to use Electron to make it work?

Comment: Oh I see... Well since Angular alone is not supposed to be used for Desktop development I would definitely suggest you use Electron alongside Angular to make it work. There are quite a lot of Tutorials about creating Desktop Apps with Angular and Electron.

Comment: @atalantus Sorry for a noob question but I still don't understand how then you would develop an app to a server that is not nodejs, for example, php. Before you could just throw the files there and be good but now? How would you do this? Use some plugin I don't know about that builds js code before sending it to the user? I'm just curious.

Comment: I think I'm not sure what you mean. You will always have to [copy your frontend files into your backend and then set up your backend to serve the frontend.](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#basic-deployment-to-a-remote-server).

Answer (score 1):

In your `tsconfig` you need change target to this `"target": "es5",`

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to disable modular build. You need to disable differential loading. In my case, because I target only Chrome I edited "browserslist" file at the root folder of my project to have this content: `last 2 Chrome versions` but if it's not suited for you here is [Browserslist config](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist)